# How to specify active profiles in Maven3

Tags: maven, profile, maven-3

Our application consists of various active profiles (say A1, A2, A3, A5 ...) which were separately defined in a profiles.xml file. Maven 3 expects all the profile information to be stored as part of the pom.xml file itself.

How should I specify the list of active profiles within a pom.xml file, so that I can avoid specifying them in the command line (e.g. mvn -PA1,A2,A3,A5)

Answer (score 10):

Should this do it:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>profile-1</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

From [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Comment: I am unable to specify this for multiple profiles, I don't think the suggestion works

Answer (score 5):

Addidional to the answer of @javamonkey79 you can use the settings.xml. There are parts of profiles and activations. Look at the following example:

```
 <profiles>
  <profile>
   <id>hudson-simulate</id>
   <properties>
    <gituser>username</gituser>
    <gitpassword>secret</gitpassword>
   </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
   <id>other-profile</id>
   <properties>
    <proerty1>username</property1>
   </properties>
  </profile>
 </profiles>

 <activeProfiles>
  <activeProfile>hudson-simulate</activeProfile>
  <activeProfile>other-profile</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>
```